# C# - Loop formatting

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, int

Having a bit of trouble with an assignment of mine. It's supposed too prompt the user to enter a range (2 integers), then using the format below display the equations that are within the range.

Example:

```
Enter minimum integer: 3
Enter maximum integer: 7

All: 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 25
Even: 4 + 6 = 10
Odd: 3 + 5 + 7 = 15
```

Not asking for the entire solution, just a bit of the loop formatting issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
            Console.Write("Enter minimum integer: ");
            string min = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter maximum integer: ");
            string max = Console.ReadLine();

            int min32 = int.Parse(min);
            int max32 = int.Parse(max);

            for (int i = min32; i <= max32; i++)
                Console.Write(i + " + ");
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far.

Comment: "I can get the loop going with the numbers adding, even, and odd" what is missing? adding the plus and the result of the SUM?

Comment: You'll want to ask a question. You are not stating what exactly isn't working. "*just a bit of the loop formatting issue*" Which is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to start outputting the numbers in the console, always checking if this is the last number which will be outputed (if that's the case, don't print the `+` after the number.)

```
Console.Write("All: ");        
int sum = 0;
for (int i = min32; i <= max32; i++)
{
    if(i != max32) //Only add " + " after the number if this is not the end of the for loop
        Console.Write(i + " + ");
    else
        Console.Write(i); 
    sum += i;
} 
Console.WriteLine(" = " + sum);
//Outputs for min32 = 3 and max32 = 7:
//3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 25
```

Bonus round: LINQ queries on an `IEnumerable<int>` returned from `Enumerable.Range()`, filtered using some `Where` statements and concatinated using a `string.Join()`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Min: ");
        int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
        Console.Write("Max: ");
        int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var sequence = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1);

        string all = "All: " + string.Join(" + ", sequence);
        string even = "Even: " + string.Join(" + ", sequence.Where(a => a % 2 == 0));
        string odd = "Odd: " + string.Join(" + ", sequence.Where(a => a % 2 == 1));

        Console.WriteLine(all + " = " + sequence.Sum());
        Console.WriteLine(even + " = " + sequence.Where(a => a % 2 == 0).Sum());
        Console.WriteLine(odd + " = " + sequence.Where(a => a % 2 == 1).Sum());

    }
}
```

Comment: :| I'm going to pound my head on the table for not thinking of that earlier... TYVM

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps keep a string for each collection of numbers. When adding to a total, also append the number to the string. Another option might be string.Join() on a list of strings, using " + " as the separator.

Once the loop finishes, print the joined lists along with the appropriate sum.